# can I use neutral in an AC circuit as the negative conductor on a separate DC circuit

Tags: ac, dc

I have a particular application, but I also generally want to know the answer.

I have an aluminium sail boat that has a extensive DC electrical system, as well as a 500watt inverter for a basic AC system.  The neutral is tied to the ground, and the ground is tied to the battery bank's negative pole. This is standard practice. FYI: The boat has a "floating ground" so the negative pole does not touch the hull.

I have a 4 core 2.5mm cable running from one side of the boat to the other, which sound simple but to keep it a clean run and hidden it is buried in, under and around all kinds of things and I never want to run another cable to that place on the boat again.

At the end of the 4 core cable I want to run a small AC bar fridge, but it is a small space so i also want to hook up one or more DC fans on a temperature controlled relay to help move hot air away from the back of the fridge.  I'm sure there are lots of ways to do this but it would be very clean to just use that 4 core cable to carry the line, neutral, earth, DC+ and share the earth or neutral for the DC negative.

thanks

Comment: Why don't you get a DC bar fridge? It would probably be a lot more efficient overall than running an AC fridge off of an inverter. Also, are you sure the inverter can even handle the compressor startup surge? Test before you commit.

Comment: Thanks, for sure your right. I'm in a 3rd world country, covid lock down, etc.  lots of better ways to skin this cat but not an option right now.  i have it set up with a DC - cable duct taped to my floor and walls, just wondering if I can not have that in my life.

Comment: The alternative would be to use a small AC-to-DC power supply behind the fridge to power the fans and their control circuit. But in any case, since the the AC ground/neutral and DC return are already bonded together, what you propose can't change the safety aspects of the setup. The only remaining question is whether that core can handle the total AC+DC current. 2.5 mm^2 wire should be able to handle up to about 15A safely.

Comment: Thanks Dave, fridge is .4 amp AC and fan might be .5 amp DC.  So cable size is looking good.  Thanks i will keep this open for a bit but I think I have my answer.